# Download seetings of google drive

Tags: download, google-drive-api, file-sharing

Is there a way to allow/deny someone to download a document that was shared with him using google drive? This question is not about sharing settings, it is about permission to download/not download a document that is already shared with a user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Google Drive, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the firebug request wile changing the rights to deny downloading the file the parameter v changes from false to true.

Then there is the insertProperty method which I used to set the key v to true but without success. I hope this gives you at least a point to start digging around.